# Using regular expression to extract string

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the IP address from the following string.

```
>>> mydns='ec2-54-196-170-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
```

The text to the left of the dot needs to be returned. The following works as expected.

```
>>> mydns[:18]
'ec2-54-196-170-182'
```

But it does not work in all cases. For e.g.

```
mydns='ec2-666-777-888-999.compute-1.amazonaws.com'

>>> mydns[:18]
'ec2-666-777-888-99'
```

How to I use regular expressions in python?

Comment: Its quite hard to give a straight regex answer since all the parts in the string are quite common...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for regex... Just use `str.split`

```
mydns.split('.', 1)[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> mydns='ec2-666-777-888-999.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
>>> mydns.split('.', 1)[0]
'ec2-666-777-888-999'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use regex for this:

### Regex String

`ec2-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3}).*`

Alternative (EC2 Agnostic):

`.*\b([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3}).*`

### Replacement String

Regular: `\1.\2.\3.\4`

Reverse: `\4.\3.\2.\1`

### Python code

```
import re
subject = 'ec2-54-196-170-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
result = re.sub("ec2-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3}).*", r"\1.\2.\3.\4", subject)

print result
```

Comment: Do you by any chance think that hardcoding the `ec2` is a good idea? The user might possibly have hundreds of similar ip's!!!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, only EC2 instances have DNS names like that. Everything else is usually specified like `aws:region:stuff:morestuff/name/items`

Comment: However you cannot predict the user has only `ec2` instances and by any chance if there were any other instances then the user is in trouble...

Comment: If that's the case, `.*\b([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3})-([0-9]{1,3}).*` can be used instead. I kinda doubt it though. I edited the main post to include the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match `(^[^.]+`:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

So Try this:

```
import re

string = "ec2-54-196-170-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
ip = re.findall('^[^.]+',string)[0]
print ip
```

Output:

```
ec2-54-196-170-182
```

Best thing is this will match even if the instance was `ec2`,`ec3` so this regex is actually very much similar to the code of @mgilson

Comment: Hmm, do you think that `^[^.]+` would be a simple enough regex to do the job?